# Best way to clean addresses in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to clean about 20 Million addresses sitting in a DB2 database (connecting using ODBC, SAS EG 4.3). Below is some sample code. This code runs for a LONG time. Is there a way to optimize it? Should this probably be attempted in a sql step rather than in a data step (I don't know if that is going to be faster)?

```
%macro addy(orig_addy,edited_addy);
*scrub original address field;
addr=upcase(&orig_addy.);

addr=(left(tranwrd(cat(' ',addr,' '),' SO. ',' S ')));

addr=compress(addr,".,()'");
addr=translate(addr, ' ', '_/-#;');

&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ NORTH / N /',-1,cat(' ',addr,' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SOUTH / S /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ EAST / E /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ WEST / W /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ NORTHWEST / NW /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SOUTHWEST / SW /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ NORTHEAST / NE /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SOUTHEAST / SE /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));

&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SAINT / ST /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/   / /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' '))); *tripple spaces;
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/  / /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' '))); *double spaces;
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ & / AND /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ @ / AT /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ INTERNATIONAL / INTL /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SUITE / STE /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ SUITES / STES /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ FLOOR | FLR / FL /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
&edited_addy.=left(prxchange('s/ BUILDING / BLDG /',-1,cat(' ',upcase(&edited_addy.),' ')));
...
...
...
```

Right now, this is running for 20 hrs for just 2 Million observations. There are way more prxchange condtions than seen here. This is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a DATA step should be fine. The reason it's slow is that you're processing every character of your address line hundreds of times for each observation. (I think SAS preparses the regular expressions if they're constant, but if not, using `PRXPARSE` may help.)

If all of your regular expressions are of the form (word) -> (normalized word), then you might be able to do it word by word and skip the regex processing altogether:

- Create a [hash object](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/dot/hash-getting-started.pdf) (or [character format](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p011-27.pdf) if you're old school) containing all the normalizations
- Split address line into words
- Normalize each word using the hash object
- Rejoin the address

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of other things you could try.

- Ending your regular expression with /o tells SAS to compile the string only once, so it shouldn't process it for each observation.
- If you are sure you only have 1 occurrence of the match for some/all of the searches, then changing the -1 to 1 should speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take just to pull the raw data into SAS (without running any regexs)?

If the above is quick then the issue may be the translation from SAS code to mySQL code that's taking place.  I don't think running a lot of regexs on 2 million observations will take much time at all as I've been through a similar process before with much more data.

You could break it up into 2 steps.

1. bring the unmodified data into SAS.
2. have sas apply the cleaning routines.